# Add Custom Labels to NLTK Information Extractor

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on an information extractor specifically purposed with parsing relationships between entities such as movies, directors, and actors. NLTK appears to provide the necessary tools to construct such a system. However, it is not clear how one would go about adding custom labels (e.g. actor, director, movie title).

Similarly, [Chapter 7 of the NLTK Book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) discusses information extraction using a named entity recognizer, but it glosses over labeling details.

So, I have two questions:

How would I add custom labels?
If I have bare lists of relevant named entities (e.g. movies, actors, etc.), how can I include them as features? It appears that I would need to use IOB format, but I am unsure about how to do this when I only have lists of named entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have your own lists of named entities, and you're only interested in extracting the relations, I believe there are simpler solutions (although I never tried relation extraction in NLTK, so I might be wrong):

- [ReVerb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/) - a tool written in Java. Once it produces the results, you can simply keep the rows, where your labels are present as objects of the relation.
- [OpenIE](http://knowitall.github.io/openie/) - the successor of ReVerb (also written in Java). The authors claim better perfomance, and the output might be more informative.
- [IEPY](http://iepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) - a relation extraction tool in Python. You should be able to provide your own labels/named entities using [gazetees](http://iepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gazettes.html).
- [MITIE](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE) - this library has bindings in Python, and it offers [relation extraction](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE/blob/master/examples/python/ner.py) functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had hoped to use NLTK entirely, but these tools look promising as well.

Answer (score -1):

Lots of keyword extraction techniques are there depends on factors like:

Grammatical quality of text.
Length of text
Are you looking for a single keyword or phrasal keyword etc.
But in general If you have long text and you want to extract keywords automatically from that, I would recommend you to go through follow articles:

1. [TextRank](https://www.thinkinfi.com/2018/09/automatic-keyword-extraction-using_30.html)
2. [Rake](https://www.thinkinfi.com/2018/09/keyword-extraction-using-rake-in-python.html) [Rapid Automatic Keyword Extraction]
3. [Topica](https://www.thinkinfi.com/2018/09/automatic-keyword-extraction-using.html)

Also to extract custom(special) keywords which is not coming through above techniques, have a look at [this post](https://www.thinkinfi.com/2018/10/extract-custom-entity-using-nltk-pos.html).